# Sending email on the loop Per Customer ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, loops, foreach, model

I have the following code that loops around and is supposed to send a single email per requested order list. So it sends multiple separated order emails for each customer rather than just the one email order list.

```
public ActionResult SaveOrder(string name, Order[] order)
{
    string result = "Error! Order Is Not Complete!";
    if (name != null && address != null && email != null  && order != null)
    {
        var cutomerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Customer model = new Customer();
        model.CustomerId = cutomerId;
        model.Name = name;
        model.Address = address;
        model.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
        model.Email = email;
        db.Customers.Add(model);


        foreach (var item in order)
        {
            var orderId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Order O = new Order();
            O.OrderId = orderId;
            O.ProductName = item.ProductName;
            O.Quantity = item.Quantity;
            O.Price = item.Price;
            O.Amount = item.Amount;
            O.CustomerId = cutomerId;
            db.Orders.Add(O);

            var customername = model.Name;

            if (model.Name != null)
            {
                //Send Email to User
                SendVerificationLinkEmail(model.Email, model.Name, O.ProductName);
            }
        }
            db.SaveChanges()                

        result = "Success! Order Is Complete!";
    }
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[NonAction]
public void SendVerificationLinkEmail(string email, string name, string productname)
{


    var fromEmail = new MailAddress("test@test.com", "Laundry");
    var toEmail = new MailAddress(email);
    var fromEmailPassword = "xxxxx"; // Replace with actual password
    string subject = "Your " + productname + " order request has been scheduled ";

    string body = "";

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/HtmlPage1.html")))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    body = body.Replace("{name}", name);
    body = body.Replace("{emailID}", email);
    body = body.Replace("{productname}", productname);



    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)

    };

    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = true

    })
        smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: What's the question? If you don't want your method to fire in the loop, don't call the method within the loop...

Comment: I want the email to be sent once and not twice(using order items). I hope I am making sense now. And if I should not call the method within the loop where should I place it, because it should work also

Comment: Well, you want the email to be sent once, but your method takes a single product name, so it's not entirely clear on how you're expecting to send more than one product name in an email apparently designed to send information about one product. That's a design decision you'll have to make.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this:

```
        foreach (var item in order)
        {
            var orderId = Guid.NewGuid();

            ... // code removed for clarity

            if (model.Name != null)
            {
                //Send Email to User
                SendVerificationLinkEmail(model.Email, model.Name, O.ProductName);
            }
        }
```

to this: (take the if statement out of the foreach loop)

```
        foreach (var item in order)
        {
            var orderId = Guid.NewGuid();

            ... // code removed for clarity

        }
        if (model.Name != null)
        {
            //Send Email to User
            SendVerificationLinkEmail(model.Email, model.Name, O.ProductName);
        }
```

will send one email per customer order, instead of one email per order item. (Although you're passing `o.ProductName` to the `SendVerificationLinkEmail` method, so the email will presumably only contain the last ProductName since that appears to be different for each line item.)

Comment: @jffttrotman I want it to send email order list per customer.